# How to get currently showing slide index in Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Doing this

```
var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
var currentPage = selection.getCurrentPage();
```

does not work, because getting selection only works for bound scripts.
I cannot find any way to get the current slide to work with it.
Any thoughts?

Thanks